# SQL grouping and sum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to know how to get the following result set out of my current result set.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3) As 'Series', b.Col2, cast(c.Price * c.Qty as money) AS Total
from tableName a
inner join ....
...
WHERE date between '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
AND B IN ('C50', 'C51', 'C52', 'C53', 'C54')
GROUP BY Col1, b.Col2, c.Price, c.Qty
```

And returns this result set:

```
Series       Col2        Total
----------   ----------  ----------
105          C50         5.00
105          C50         15.00
105          C53         20.00
105          C53         20.00
105          C53         20.00
```

And this is how I would like it to work:

```
Series       Col2        Total
----------   ----------  ----------
105          C50         20.00
105          C53         60.00
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the computed column : `SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3)` .

```
SELECT sub.Series, sub.Col2, SUM(sub.Total)
FROM
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3) As 'Series', b.Col2, cast(c.Price * c.Qty as money) AS Total
from tableName a inner join ....
  ...
WHERE date between '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
  AND B IN ('C50', 'C51', 'C52', 'C53', 'C54') 
) as sub
GROUP BY sub.Series, sub.Col2
```

Comment: I receive this error:

Column 'Col1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @hype there's no group by or aggregate in my subquery.  There's no col1 in my outer query.  You must have made a typo.

Comment: Sorry, yes I made a typo. After I fixed it however, everything seemed correct except one sum was not being totaled correctly. I found that it was creating a copy of a row. So I added a grouping to the inner query which fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just group on the unaggregated columns, like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3) As 'Series', b.Col2, 
    sum(cast(c.Price * c.Qty as money)) AS Total
from tableName a
inner join ....
...
WHERE date between '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
AND B IN ('C50', 'C51', 'C52', 'C53', 'C54')
GROUP BY Col1, b.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy. Group just using `Col1` and `Col2` as grouping criteria and sum up you expression `CAST(c.Price * c.Qty as money)`:

```
SELECT 
   SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3) As 'Series', 
   b.Col2, 
   SUM(CAST(c.Price * c.Qty as money)) AS Total
FROM tableName a
inner join ....
...
WHERE date between '1/1/2012' and '1/31/2012'
AND B IN ('C50', 'C51', 'C52', 'C53', 'C54')
GROUP BY Col1, b.Col2
```